# Whenever I make changes to my Java class in IntelliJ IDEA, my Appium tests start running automatically

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, appium-android

I am currently testing my app using Appium and Selenium in IntelliJ IDEA, running the tests in Java.

The problem I'm encountering is that, following the successful execution and completion of my tests, whenever I make edits to any of my classes—particularly the test class—my script starts running automatically.

I've attempted several solutions like

1. Restored it to default settings
2. [Disabling auto-test](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171799)
3. Uninstalled completely IntelliJ IDEA and reinstalled it

But regrettably, the problem persists.

As a last resort, I've turned to the Stack Overflow community as a last option.

Additionally, I'm curious to know if this problem might be related to IntelliJ IDEA itself, a potential issue with my laptop, or if there's another factor at play here.

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.